# Sending multiple HTML form data to Google sheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting an array of objects (JSON collection) data that we need to send to Google sheets using Google script.

The problem is that I am unable to write the logic to send multiple records at a time to Google sheets.

Sample output from the above code:

```
json---[{"name":"mob","email":"mob@gmail.com","employeeId":"mob1","category":"Celebration","reason":"na","currency":"INR","amount":"68787","date":"2022-08-17T15:19"},{"name":"kob","email":"kob@hmail.com","employeeId":"kob1","category":"Internet Connection","reason":"na","currency":"USD","amount":"6767","date":"2022-08-17T15:19"},{"name":"lob","email":"lob@ymai.com","employeeId":"lob1","category":"Celebration","reason":"na","currency":"INR","amount":"657","date":"2022-08-17T15:19"}]
```

**This is the code we are written**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\categories\categories\favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Twenty20Systems</title>
<!--- add icon -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!---delete icon -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <!--jquery -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #f3c5d4e3;
  padding: 8px;
}

.submitBtn{
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
}

body  {
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-image: url(bg.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", serif;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="C:\Users\info\Desktop\form\New folder\logo.png" alt="Logo" width="200">
    </div>
<h2 style="color: white; text-align: center;"> Expense Submission Form</h2>
<form id ='CustomerForm'>
<table id="listCtg">
  <tr >
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Employee ID</th>
    <th>Expense Category</th>
    <th>Reason for Expense</th>
    <th>Currency</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Date of expense</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row0" >
    <td><input id="name0" value ="" type='text'></td>
    <td><input id="email0" value ="" type='email'></td>
    <td><input id="empId0" value ="" type='text'></td>
    <td>
    <select id="category0" value ="">
    <option>choose category</option>
    <option>Accommodation</option>
    <option>Celebration</option>
    <option>Certifications/Training</option>
    <option>Client Expense</option>
    <option>Hardware (Laptop, Headphones, Mouse)</option>
    <option>Gym</option>
    <option>Internet Connection</option>
    <option>choose meals</option>
    <option>aaa</option>
    <option>bbb</option>
    <option>Swags</option>
    <option>Transport</option>
    <option>Tution reimbursement</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input id="reason0" value ="" type='text'></td>
    <td><select id="currency0" value ="">
    <option>choose currency</option>
    <option>INR</option>
    <option>USD</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type='text' id="amount0" value =""></td>
    <td> <input type="date" id="date0" value =""></td>
    <td><i  onclick ="deleteRow(id)"  class="fa fa-trash" id="Row0" ></i></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
<div class='submitBtn'>
 <span id='addRow' class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="color: white;"></span>
<input type='button' id='submitBtn' value='Submit'>
</div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//var tblLength = $('#listCtg tr').length-1;
var i=1;
$('#addRow').click (function(){
$('#listCtg').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input id="name'+i+'" value ="" type="text"></td><td><input type="email" id="email'+i+'" value =""></td><td><input type="text" id="empId'+i+'" value =""></td><td><select id="category'+i+'" value =""><option>choose category</option><option>Accommodation</option><option>Celebration</option><option>Certifications/Training</option><option>Client Expense</option><option>Hardware (Laptop, Headphones, Mouse)</option><option>Gym</option><option>Internet Connection</option><option>Meals</option><option>Swags</option><option>Transport</option><option>Tution reimbursement</option></select></td><td><input id="reason'+i+'" value ="" type="text"></td><td><select id="currency'+i+'" value =""><option>choose currency</option><option>INR</option><option>USD</option></select></td><td><input id="amount'+i+'" value ="" type="text"></td><td> <input id="date'+i+'" value ="" type="date"></td><td><i  onclick ="deleteRow(id)"  class="fa fa-trash" id="Row'+i+'"></i></td></tr>');
i++;
})
$('#submitBtn').click (function(){
var jsonArray =[];
var tblLength = $('#listCtg tr').length-1;
const form = document.getElementById('CustomerForm');   

console.log(tblLength)
for(var i=0;i<tblLength;i++){
    console.log("abc"+i)
    var json ={name:$('#name'+i).val(),email:$('#email'+i).val(),employeeId:$('#empId'+i).val(),
            category:$('#category'+i).val(),reason:$('#reason'+i).val(),currency:$('#currency'+i).val(),
            amount:$('#amount'+i).val(),date:$('#date'+i).val()}
            jsonArray.push(json);
            // alert(i,JSON.stringify(json));

for (i=0;i<= jsonArray.length;i++)
{   
   
    
    console.log("insideloop" + JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
    var Name = jsonArray[i].name;
    var Email = jsonArray[i].email;
    var employeeId = jsonArray[i].employeeId;
    var category = jsonArray[i].category;
    var reason = jsonArray[i].reason;
    var currency = jsonArray[i].currency;
    var amount = jsonArray[i].amount;
    debugger;  
    var info = {
          Name: Name.value,
          Email: Email.value,
          EmployeeId: employeeId.value,
          Reason: reason.value,
          Currency:currency.value,
          Amount: amount.value
    
};
 var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwgOPF3G4BKd-bX83iz7UkAvGSUEd6re0IdGqsLRozmW03OgJu82yEjAIWjNIBt3gNu/exec";
    
    // const form = document.getElementById('CustomerForm');    
    const form = document.forms['CustomerForm']

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
              e.preventDefault()
              fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(info)})
                .then(response => console.log('Success!', response,alert("ssss")))
                .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message,alert("ssss")))
            })
// function afterSubmit(e){
//  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
//        e.preventDefault();
//     debugger;
   
// debugger;
//  fetch(url,{
// method: 'POST',
// cache: 'no-cache',
// redirect: 'follow',
// body: JSON.stringify(jsonArray)
// })
// .then(res => res.json())
// .then(res => {
//    console.log(res);
//    customerForm.reset();
// })
// .catch(err => {
//    console.log(err);
//    console.log("Something Went Wrong");
// });

// // customerForm.addEventListener("submit",afterSubmit);      

// });
}
// const form = document.getElementById('CustomerForm');    
// form.addEventListener('submit',afterSubmit(jsonArray));  



}

console.log('json---'+JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
})
})
function deleteRow(id){
result = id.slice(3, 4);
$('#row'+result).remove();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, this is the code that we are using right now for my use case and could you kindly help us to finish the task if you are comfortable we can connect through my mailid vinaynk456@gmail.com

Comment: How are you execting this code?  From an HTMLService dialog?  If so you should look at [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]

Comment: @Cooper Hello cooper i have added complete code in the above and could you kindly help us to finish the task if you are comfortable we can connect through my mailid vinaynk456@gmail.com thankyou for your prompt response

Comment: @TheWizEd we have referred https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175 this link and trying to impliment the as per my requirement but couldn't able to complete

Comment: Your button is not of type `submit`.